# prevent span in td contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use contenteditable in td

```
<table style="width:200px">
<tr>
    <td contenteditable  style="width:100px" id="1">test</td>
    <td contenteditable  style="width:100px" id="2">test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

when I enter more text in the first td, it make the second td become smaller, then table will bigger than 200px that I specified before, how can I prevent that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZNj3/1/

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable>this long text won't overflow</td>
        <td contenteditable>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table {
    width: 200px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<table style="max-width:200px;">
<tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" style="max-width:100px; word-wrap: break-word;" id="1">test</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"  style="width:100px;" id="2">test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: great, maybe this is the best choice althought I still want to make it to work like <input> ( it don't span and don't create new line ). Tks very much.